# Assigning Pydantic Fields not by alias

Tags: python, pydantic

How can I create a pydantic object, without useing alias names?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Params(BaseModel):
    var_name: int = Field(alias='var_alias')

Params(var_alias=5) # works
Params(var_name=5) # does not work
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As of the pydantic 2.0 release, this behaviour has been updated to use model_config `populate_by_name` option which is `False` by default.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, ConfigDict


class Params(BaseModel):
    var_name: int = Field(alias='var_alias')

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        populate_by_name=True,
    )

Params(var_alias=5)  # works
Params(var_name=5)   # works
```

For pydantic 1.x, you need to use `allow_population_by_field_name` [model config](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/model_config/) option.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Params(BaseModel):
    var_name: int = Field(alias='var_alias')

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


Params(var_alias=5)  # works
Params(var_name=5)   # works
```

Comment: its a lifesaver! - might be because am a beginner in this!

Comment: This form of configuration [has been deprecated](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/model_config/).

Comment: Added edit - use `populate_by_name` for pydantic 2.x within the `model_config`

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for hours this morning and afternoon! I searched and searched the pydantic docs and maybe it's there but it is NOT prominent, that's for sure!!!!