# Assigning Pydantic Settings Fields not by alias even when environment variable is defined

Tags: python, pydantic, pydantic-settings

I’d like to be able to create a Pydantic Settings object where the environment variable can be overriden if desired. In the example below the constructor call for `user_3` fails:

```py
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict
import os

class User(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)
    name: str = Field(alias='full_name')  
    age: int

user_1 = User(full_name='John Doe', age=20)  
print(user_1) # >> name='John Doe' age=20
user_2 = User(name='John Doe', age=20)  
print(user_2) # >> name='John Doe' age=20
os.environ["full_name"] = "foo"
user_3 = User(name='John Doe', age=20)  # >> error (see below)
print(user_3)
```

with this message:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
name
  Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value='John Doe', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/extra_forbidden
```

Is there a way to set up the object such that `populate_by_name` works (`user_3` constructor call) even when an environment variable exists?

Thanks!

Related question - [Assigning Pydantic Fields not by alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433904/assigning-pydantic-fields-not-by-alias)

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```py
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict
import os

class User(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)
    full_name: str = Field(alias='name')  
    age: int

user_1 = User(full_name='John Doe', age=20)  
print(user_1) # >> name='John Doe' age=20
user_2 = User(name='John Doe', age=20)  
print(user_2) # >> name='John Doe' age=20
os.environ["full_name"] = "foo"
user_3 = User(name='John Doe', age=20)
print(user_3)
```

This one as well:

```py
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict
import os

class User(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)
    name: str = Field(alias='full_name')  
    age: int

user_1 = User(full_name='John Doe', age=20)  
print(user_1) # >> name='John Doe' age=20
user_2 = User(name='John Doe', age=20)  
print(user_2) # >> name='John Doe' age=20
os.environ["full_name"] = "foo"
user_3 = User(full_name='John Doe', age=20)
print(user_3)
```

I think that may be a pydantic bug. Anyways, that's some workarounds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, but those examples populate by the alias name and not the class name which is what I am looking for.